# Intuitively, why does $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac16 (p_{n - 1} + p_{n - 2} ... + p_{n - 6}) = 2/7$?

Tags: probability

Blitzstein, *Introduction to Probability* (2019 2 edn), Chapter 2, Exercise 48, p 94.

> 48. A fair die is rolled repeatedly, and a running total is kept (which is, at each time, the total of all the rolls up until that time). Let $p_n$ be the probability that the running total is ever exactly n (assume the die will always be rolled enough times so that the running total will eventually exceed n, but it may or may not ever equal n).
>
> (c) Give an intuitive explanation for the fact that $p_n \rightarrow  1/3.5 = 2/7 \quad as \quad n \rightarrow \infty$.

From p 17 in the publicly downloadable PDF of curbed solutions.

> (c)An intuitive explanation is as follows. The average number thrown by the die is (total of dots)/6, which is 21/6 = 7/2, so that every throw adds on an average of 7/2. ***We can therefore expect to land on 2 out of every 7 numbers, and the probability of landing on any particular number is 2/7.***

That's the line I don't get it, why we can transfer

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1867959/1008726

Answer (score 5):

I explain this *informal* argument slightly differently. Let $p(i)$ be the probability that the running total equals $i$ at some point.

1. Note that $k = p(1) + \dots + p(n)$ equals the expected number of values between $1$ and $n$ that the running sum takes (by the linearity of expectation). Specifically, let ${\cal E}_i$ be the event that the running sum takes value $i$ and $e_i$ be the indicator variable of the event ${\cal E}_i$ (that is, $e_i =1$ if ${\cal E}_i$ happens; $e_i=0$, otherwise). Then the expected number of values the running sum takes equals
   $$\mathbb{E}[e_1 + \dots + e_n] = \mathbb{E}[e_1] + \dots + \mathbb{E}[e_n] = \mathrm{Pr}[{\cal E}_1] + \dots + \mathrm{Pr}[{\cal E}_n] = p(1) + \dots p(n).$$
2. Since the average increment is $7/2$, we have that $k \approx \frac{2}{7} n$.
3. On the other hand, intuitively all values $p(i)$ are *approximately equal* (this is not true for small values of $i$; but it is true for large values of $i$).

Thus $\frac{2}{7} n \approx p(1) + \dots p(n) \approx n p(n)$. Therefore, $p(n) \approx 2/7$.

Comment: That's quite interesting, but i don't get the idea of k=p(1)+⋯+p(n), since i think P(.) is probability, it should multiply the corresponding value to become expectation, is that right?

Comment: I think i need more example for this, since now it seems i fell into mess and still don't get the idea...

Comment: I added an explanation why k = p(1) + ... + p(n).

Comment: the indicator variable is very nice, thanks for your explanation! Can u also help me identify the 2nd point?

Comment: After each step, the sum increases by 7/2 in expectation. Thus after r steps it increases by 7r/2 in expectation. Moreover, the sum is “very close” to 7r/2 with high probability (by the Law of Large Numbers or the Central Limit Theorem). Therefore, the sum reaches n after approximately 2n/7 steps.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to think of it. Suppose you throw the die 1000 times. What sum will you get? Well, of course, it could be anything from 1000 to 6000, but you *expect* it to be pretty near 3500, right? So, you expect to get 1000 numbers on the way to the sum 3500. Well, getting 1000 numbers out of 3500 is getting, *on average*, 2 numbers out of every 7. Landing on 1000 numbers on the way to 3500 is landing on two-sevenths of the numbers. So the probability of landing on any particular number is 2/7.

Comment: "So, you expect to get 1000 numbers on the way to the sum 3500." I got the idea that i expect there are 1000 numbers (each of them could be 1 to 6) and sum them up to be 3500. Well, getting 1000 numbers out of 3500 is getting, on average, 2 numbers out of every 7.

Comment: but i still can't get the next sentence that 1000 numbers out of 3500 ....

Comment: Let me rephrase it: you expect to *land on* 1000 numbers on the way to 3500. So on average you land on two-sevenths of the numbers; two numbers out of every seven. Is that better?

Comment: Sorry that i kept asking the same idea, when we expect to land on 1000 numbers on the way to 3500, does that mean i expect throw 1000 times dice and get the sum 3500?

Comment: If you throw the die 1000 times, you expect to get a sum pretty near 3500. If you throw it 10,000 times, you expect a sum near 35,000. If you throw it 1,000,000 times, you expect a sum near 3,500,000. Wait. let's try this: say you throw it 600 times. You expect to get about 100 1s, 100 2s, ..., 100 6s, and those numbers add up to $100+200+\cdots+600=2100$, and 600 is to 2100 as 2 is to 7. If you roll the die $Q$ times, you expect a sum near $(7/2)Q$; so, to get the sum $n$, you expect to roll the die about $(2/7)n$ times (and thus land on about $(2/7)n$ numbers).

Comment: Yap, so i expect to get n from 2/7(n) steps. Then how to get the idea of P(n)=2/7?

Comment: So you land on 2 numbers out of every 7. So your chances of ever landing on any particular number must be ... 2 out of 7! $P(n)$ is just the probability that you land on $n$, and since you land on 2 numbers out of every 7, $P(n)=2/7$.

Comment: Thanks! I think i figure it out eventually!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, consider that you may start with any small random number. Then each step you increase by '1'. What is the probability that you will reach a specific big number? Intuitively, your answer should be 1.
Now, what if your increment is '$2$'? Again, the probability should be $(0.5=\frac{1}{2})$ to reach a specific large number. 
For our problem, it's found that on average we increase the total by (7/2=3.5). This should give intuitive impression that our probability to reach a large number is $(\frac{1}{3.5}=\frac{2}{7})$.