# Calculate the probability that the running total is exactly n. (homework help)

Tags: probability

I am working through Harvard's public [Stat 110](http://projects.iq.harvard.edu/stat110) (probability) course.

Question:

5. A fair die is rolled repeatedly, and a running total is kept (which is, at each time, the total of all the rolls up until that time). Let $p_n$ be the probability that the running total is ever exactly n (assume the die will always be rolled enough times so that the running total will eventually exceed n, but it may or may not ever equal n).

   (a) Write down a recursive equation for $p_n$ (relating $p_n$ to earlier terms $p_k$ in a simple way). Your equation should be true for all positive integers n, so give a definition of $p_0$ and $p_k$ for $k < 0$ so that the recursive equation is true for small values of n.

   (b) Find $p_7$.

   (c) Give an intuitive explanation for the fact that $p_n \rightarrow 1/3.5=2/7$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

My work so far:

I am working on part a. So far, my ideas for a recursive formula are as follows.

We can get to $n$ by being at $n-1$ and rolling a 1, being at $n-2$ and rolling a 2, and so on. So,

$p_n = \frac{1}{6}p_{n-1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{6}p_{n-6}$.

In order for this to work for small values of $n$, let $p_0 = 1$ and $p_n = 0$ for all $n < 0$.

After working out $p_n$ for some small values of $n$, I believe the above is equivalent to

$p_n = \sum\limits_{k=n-6}^n \frac{1}{6^k}{n \choose k} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^6 \frac{1}{6^{n-k}}{n \choose 6-k}$

However, in either case, it seems that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $p_n \rightarrow \infty$ (looking at part c given my definition of $p_n$ so far). Can someone point out where I've gone astray?

Edit: It seems I was overcomplicating the problem by assuming that I'd need a closed form equation for $p_n$. This means that I have what I need for part a, and I can calculate part b. I'm still working on an intuitive answer for part c.

Comment: The "closed form" for $p_n$ is not right.

Comment: Meaning the second equation?

Comment: Yes, the first is a recurrence.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007576. Note that the homogeneous equation is the same; only the inhomogeneous part and the initial conditions differ.

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed. Listing out examples quickly becomes tedious. Do you have a hint? A different way to think about the problem?

Comment: They don't ask you to find a closed form (good thing they don't!). They do ask you to come up with values for $p_{-5}$ up to $p_0$ so that the recurrence will work for even small positive $n$. That can be done tediously or by making a "lucky" guess. The intuitive reason for c) does not require a closed form.

Comment: Right, I forgot to include the definitions of $p_0$ and $p_n$ for $n<0$. I will add those.

Comment: So perhaps I was just making this more complicated than it needed to be by assuming there is a nice, closed form answer. Would it be appropriate to delete this question?

Comment: The post should not be deleted. You did find the recurrence correctly (I would prefer to condition on the first throw rather than the last.) But the suitable "initial" conditions are a bit of an unusual question, and c) is worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a bit of bookkeeping to get the first few cases $p_0 ... p_6$.  Those you can hit on the first roll (but may not).

First, $p_0 = 1$, because you start there.

Next, $p_1 = 1/6$.  You roll a $1$ on the first roll, or not.

Next, $p_2 = 1/6^2 + 1/6$.  You can roll a $2$, or two $1$s.

Next, $p_3 = 1/6^3 + 2/6^2 + 1/6$.  Three $1$s, a $1$ and a $2$ (two ways), or one $3$.

Next, $p_4 = 1/6^4 + 3/6^3 + 3/6^2 + 1/6$. Four $1$s, two $1$s and a $2$, two $2$s or a $1$ and a $3$, or one $4$.

Next, $p_5 = 1/6^5 + 4/6^4 + 6/6^3 + 4/6^2 + 1/6$. Five $1$s, three $1$s and a $2$, two $2$s and a $1$ or two $1$s and a $3$, a $2$ and a $3$ or a $4$ and a $1$, or a $5$.

Next, $p_6 = 1/6^6 + 5/6^5 + 10/6^4 + 10/6^3 + 5/6^2 + 1/6$. Six $1$s, four  $1$s and a $2$, two $2$s and two $1$s or one $3$ and three $1$s, one $4$ and two $1$s or $1,2,3$ or three $2$s, any two numbers that add to $6$, or one $6$.

Now, we can look at your recurrence relation.

$$p_7 = 1/6^7 + 6/6^6 + 15/6^5 + 20/6^4 + 15/6^3 + 6/6^2.$$

So far, so good.  But I think this is different than your formula.  Looking at this I'd see:

$$p_n = \sum_{k=0}^{5}\frac{1}{6^{n-k}}{n-1 \choose k}.$$

Does this continue?  I'd have to work it out myself but maybe you can give it a try. :)

Comment: I think you can make the bookkeeping easier by just starting out with: $p_n=0$ for $n<0$, and $p_0=1.$ Apply the recurrence relation from that point on.

Comment: @MitchellSpector that is way easier.  Didn't think of that!

Comment: After working on this problem for a bit, I realized you can simplify the equations for $p_1,...,p_6$ using the following pattern. $p_1 = 1/6(1/6 + 1)^0$, $p_2 = 1/6(1/6 + 1)^1$, $p_3 = 1/6(1/6 + 1)^2$, and so on. This makes calculating $p_7$ less tedious.

Comment: 1. Can you please write the meanings of $p_4, ..., p_6$ just like you did for $p_1, ..., p_3$? 2. In $p_4$, why $3/6^2$? There are only 2 ways of rolling (2, 2). 3. In $p_5$, why $4/6^2$? There are only 2 ways of rolling (2, 3). 4. In $p_6$, why $10/6^4$? You're referring to the permutation (1, 1, 2, 2). 5. Why $10/6^3$? You're referring to (1, 2, 3). 6. Why $5/6^2$? You're referring to (5, 1).

Comment: Pls edit your answer, rather than replying in comments?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on John's answer, which answers parts a and b. For part c, if $X$ is the random event of rolling a die, then $E(X) = 3.5$. We can interpret this as meaning the roll will "hit" 1 in every 3.5 numbers. More intuitively, we will hit 2 in 7 numbers on average. This explains why $p \rightarrow 2/7$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.